# Can I include into a static library another static library that uses Windows API?

Tags: c++, c, windows, cmake, static

I am working on a project called **A**, which at some point uses an open-source an open-source **library B** (https://github.com/open-license-manager/licensecc) that I compiled from the sources. **I would like A.exe to be completly independent of libraryB and of any other dependencies of libraryB.** When compiling project A, I want to only have to include library B and not worry about any other sub-dependencies.

The library B is compiled into a static library *"libraryB.lib"*. I included it in my project A by adding `target_link_librairies(libraryB)` in my CMakeLists.txt.

When compiling project A, I get a *LNK2019 link error* indicating that a symbol used inside library B is not found - in this case, it's the symbol *BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider* which comes from *Win32 bcrypt.h*.

My questions are :

- If my library B is compiled as static, shouldn't it already include every needed source from its dependencies ?
- Would compiling library B as a dynamic .dll library eliminate all dependencies on *bcrypt.h* ? (from libraryA point of view)
- I don't get any error when compiling library B, so should library A
  include the *bcrypt* library in its CMake configuration ? Would that
  solve my problem ?

Note that bcrypt.h and most of Win32 functions seem to be already compiled in .lib, and we don't have access to the source code.

I guess I am confused about static and dynamic librairies and how they are supposed to interact with each others.

Comment: ***If my library B is compiled as static, shouldn't it already include every needed source from its dependencies ?*** No it does not combine all of the static libraries into one.

Comment: ***Would compiling library B as a dynamic .dll library eliminate all dependencies on bcrypt.h ?*** It should.